# Solve $f \cdot f''' = f' \cdot f''$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Given that $f$ is a function from reals to reals such that $f(0) = 0$, and that $f \not\equiv 0$, what are the solutions to $$f \cdot f''' = f' \cdot f''?$$

Comment: Does $f\cdot f'''-f'\cdot f''$ remind you of something?

Comment: Or $\dfrac{g'}{g}$?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange.  Isn't $f(x)=x$ a solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to @Arthur's comment, one has
\begin{align*}
ff''' = f'f'' \Longleftrightarrow ff''' - f'f'' = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \frac{ff''' - f'f''}{f^{2}} = 0 \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{f''}{f}\right)' = 0 \Longleftrightarrow f'' = kf
\end{align*}

Can you take it from here?

Comment: I think I can, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

$$f \cdot f''' = f' \cdot f'' \implies \frac {f'''}{f''}=\frac {f'}{f}$$

Integrate and you get $$\ln |f''|=\ln|f|+c$$

$$f''=kf$$

This could be solved easily to get $$ f=\sinh (\lambda x)$$